# Alternative for the ImageCapture API for better browser support

Tags: javascript, ocr, tesseract, video-capture, mediastream

I use an OCR in order to recognize text from images. I take photos/snapshots from the user's camera/video input using the [ImageCapture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture) from a [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream). Here is the code responsible for that:

```
function getBlobFromMediaStream() {
    const videoTrack = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0]

    const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(videoTrack);

    return imageCapture.takePhoto().then(blob => {
        if (!blob) throw "Photo could not be taken";

        return blob;
    })
}
```

Too bad that this API doesn't work on a lot of browsers (Firefox, IE, Safari). Is there an alternative that can be used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could make a fallback with a `HTMLVideoElement` and a `HTMLCanvasElement`.
First check if your browser supports the MediaStream Image Capture API by checking if the constructor exists in the window object.

```
if ('ImageCapture' in window) { 
  // Has support for API.
} else {
  // No support, use fallback.
}
```

Then based on that either use the API or use your fallback.

In the fallback create a video element, canvas element and a canvas context. Set the `MediaStreamTrack` as the `srcObject` of the video element. The video is able to decode the data and make an actual picture.

Use the image of the video to draw an image to the canvas element with the [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) method. With this the canvas element will draw an image of the current frame in the video.

Now you can extract the data that has been drawn on the canvas and turn it into a `Blob` with the [`HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method.

**Wrap the function call inside a `Promise` for two reasons:**

1. You'll need to extract the blob from the callback, a Promise wrapper can help you do this.
2. The `ImageCapture.takePhoto()` method also returns a Promise. So you'll have the same behavior as you would have when the API is supported.

All put together it would look like this.

```
function getBlobFromMediaStream(stream) {

  if ('ImageCapture' in window) {

    const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(videoTrack);
    return imageCapture.takePhoto();
    
  } else {

    const video = document.createElement('video');
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    video.srcObject = stream;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      video.addEventListener('loadeddata', async () => {
        const { videoWidth, videoHeight } = video;
        canvas.width = videoWidth;
        canvas.height = videoHeight;

        try {
          await video.play();
          context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight);
          canvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/png');
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
    });

  }
  
}
```

Call your function like in the example below. I've discarded the `throw` statement so that all *rejected* states will be caught at the same point when you call the `getBlobFromMediaStream` function.

According to the docs of [`ImageCapture.takePhoto()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture/takePhoto), you either get a `Blob` when the promise has fulfilled and an error when it has rejected.

Same goes for the fallback. The only difference there is that the `HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()` function throws a `SecurityError` if the bitmap of the canvas is not origin clean.

```
getBlobFromMediaStream(mediaStream).then(blob => {
  // Work with your blob.
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(`Photo could not be taken. ${error}`);
})
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the comprehensive explanation! HTMLVideoElement and HTMLCanvasElement are very good alternatives with [95%+](https://caniuse.com/#search=HTMLCanvasElement) browser support